# Porque al cambiar la validacion en el evento onchage no me funciona

Tags: jquery, validación, eventos

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código.

```
$('#selDocTipo').change(function () {
    var $optionSelected = $("#selDocTipo option:selected")
    var TipoDocId = $optionSelected.val();
    // dni 8 pasaporte 10 tarjeta de secretaria
    $("#txtNumDocProm").val("");
    $("#txtNumDocProm").attr('disabled', false);
    if (TipoDocId == 47) {
        //dni
        $("#txtNumDocProm").attr('maxlength', '8');
        $("#txtNumDocProm").attr('onkeypress', 'ValidaNumvit(event)');
    } else if (TipoDocId == 51) {
        //Pasaporte
        $("#txtNumDocProm").attr('maxlength', '12');

    } else if (TipoDocId == 52) {
        //Carnet Extranjeria
        $("#txtNumDocProm").attr('maxlength', '12');
    }
});
```

Mi html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Tip. Doc.. : </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="selectpicker" id="selDocTipo" >
                <option value="47">DNI</option>
                <option value="51">Pasaporte</option>
                <option value="52">Carnet de Extrangeria</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="txtNumDocProm" class="form-control" placeholder="Nº de Documento" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

mi funcion ValidaNumvit es.

```
function ValidaNumvit(event) {
    var keycode = event.which;
    if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Sucede que cuando selecciono **primero** DNI, cumple todo pero, luego si selecciono otra opción se queda aceptándome solo números. Es como si lo guardara en caché, o no sé, pero cuando seleciono otra opción **primero** normal me acepta todo caracter, pero vuelvo a seleccionar `dni`, ya se quedo con solo números hasta que actualice la página.

Alguien sabe porque sucede eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu evento `onkeypress` se queda activado. Tienes que quitarlo cuando seleccionas otro valor con

```
$("#txtNumDocProm").removeAttr('onkeypress');
```

Este es el ejemplo completo

```js
function ValidaNumvit(event) {
  var keycode = event.which;
  if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

$(function() {
  function changeEvt() {
    var $optionSelected = $("#selDocTipo option:selected")
    var TipoDocId = $optionSelected.val();
    var txtNumDocProc = $("#txtNumDocProm");

    // Elimino cualquier evento anterior
    txtNumDocProc.removeAttr('onkeypress');

    // dni 8 pasaporte 10 tarjeta de secretaria
    txtNumDocProc.val("");
    txtNumDocProc.attr('disabled', false);
    if (TipoDocId == 47) {
      //dni
      txtNumDocProc.attr('maxlength', '8');
      txtNumDocProc.attr('onkeypress', 'ValidaNumvit(event)');
    } else if (TipoDocId == 51) {
      //Pasaporte
      txtNumDocProc.attr('maxlength', '12');

    } else if (TipoDocId == 52) {
      //Carnet Extranjeria
      txtNumDocProc.attr('maxlength', '12');
    }
  }

  $('#selDocTipo').change(changeEvt);

  changeEvt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Tip. Doc.. :</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="selDocTipo">
      <option value="47">DNI</option>
      <option value="51">Pasaporte</option>
      <option value="52">Carnet de Extrangeria</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" id="txtNumDocProm" class="form-control" placeholder="Nº de Documento" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Te recomiendo que cachees tus selectores, usas `$("#txtNumDocProm")` siete veces, si lo almacenas en una variable tu aplicación funcionará más rápidamente. También debes ejecutar la lógica del evento `change` cuando se carge el DOM para que las validaciones se hagan correctamente.